# Android custom overlay on mapview with border and image?

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview

I have a requirement to display a set of custom overlay on mapview that contain an image that is downloaded from the internet. In the past i have extended Overlay and overrode draw to create the pin by drawing bitmaps and shapes onto the canvas. Is there an alternative approach to this that will allow me to overlay the map with an ImageView at a specified lat/long? I am asking as I have a custom ImageView implementation that downloads and caches images and it would be nice to re-use it in this case.

Thanks

Comment: you think you can keep a ArrayList<ImageView> and then for each overlay keep a list of Drawable or bitmap too and get it from each ImageView, should be possible to do

Comment: thank you, but how to create border for images in arraylist?